# Terminology - What is the complement of memoization?

Tags: duplicates, terminology, memoization, redundancy

If I am correct, memoization is associated with **READ** operations. What is the term which refers to the same technique used for **WRITE** operations?

**Example**:

Let's say an app receives the following inputs,

0 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 2 1 2 5 5 5 5 3

Instead of saving everything, we tune the app to save only the transitions. (i.e ignore consecutive duplicates)

0 1 **2** 3 4 **3** **4** 2 1 2 **5** 3

What is the (standard) term that can be used to describe the above technique?

*I feel bad about using the same term since the final outcome is quite different. In READ operations, if memoization is used, the final outcome will remain the same. But in above example for WRITE operations, the final output is different from the original input.*

Comment: That is how compression may work :)

Comment: @Antoniossss I never thought of it that way, but it really makes sense. I might end up using "compression". Let's see

Comment: Except that this transformation is not reversible ... and compression is more-or-less reversible.

Comment: My bad on not mentioning the actual use case. In my case, when duplicates are omitted, the count is tracked. So I think @Antoniossss explanation matches with mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Deduplication of adjacent/most-recent entries". Your example looks like what the `uniq` tool does.

If you preserved the count of duplicates, it would be a form of RLE (run-length encoding).

As an aside, I guess you mean memoization as a way to speed up reads, and this as a method to speed up writes, but I wouldn't say that's the opposite of memoization, since it's opposite of the general goal, but not related to the particular method.

Comment: The term RLE is new to me. But I think what I am doing is quite similar. The only difference I see is that, instead of encoding the count inline, I use a hash map to store the duplicates count.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no applicable terminology for what you are asking.

And it is NOT memoization ... or (to my mind) the reverse of memorization.

(Likewise, there is no word in English for a cat with three legs.)

Comment: There is, its threeleggedcat

Comment: Yeah. I used the term memoization, just because, this technique also remembers something to do the optimization

Comment: @StephenC Yeah it could be indeed:) Drei(legged)katze ?? xD

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda -  By your logic, the word for a three-legged cat would be stool.  Because it has three legs.

Comment: @StephenC Ouch :D But this is the only way I could think of to ask this question

Comment: Fair enough.  But I still think the correct answer is "no term exists for this concept".

Comment: that's heart breaking. This particular technique saved thousands of dollars for the company I am working on. Too bad it doesn't have a name

Comment: OK.  I will invent a term for you.  "Sprodulation".  Feel free to use it in your company :-)